# Visual Studio designer opens click event code when trying to select a control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2010. However I also have had this issue in the recent past with Visual Studio 2008.

When I simply single click a control to select it, the designer acts as if I double-clicked the control and the code behind window opens for the default event for that control. If the event doesn't exists, a stub is created, one for each control that i have selected.

This was so frequent tonight that I had to post this question! What causes this, and is there any way to correct it? If not, is there a way to turn off this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My mouse was the problem. Sometimes it registered a double-click when I would single-click. I got a new mouse a month ago and haven't seen the problem since! Fingers crossed.

Comment: You might also want to reconnect the old mouse and see if the issue reappears. Also, Connect the old mouse to an other computer and see if the issue comes up there. It doesn't have to be the mouse **alone**.